# Can't display the correct frequency of integers in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

I just started with C++. The prompt is to " **display the frequency of integers in the given array** "

The following is the code that I have written:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
array <unsigned int,20> n = {1, 2, 5, 4, 3, 5, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2};

for(size_t i = 0; i < n[i]; i++)
 {
    int count = 0;
    for(size_t j = 0; j < n.size(); j++)
    {
        if (n[i] == n[j])
        {
             count++; 
        }
    }
    cout<<"Frequency of "<<n[i]<<" is "<<count<<endl;
 }
return 0;
}
```

But my output is :

> Frequency of 1 is 3
> Frequency of 2 is 5
> Frequency of 5 is 2
> Frequency of 4 is 2

Why isn't the frequency of 3 showing up? I am pretty sure it's a silly mistake but I can't pin point where.

Comment: What is the purpose of `i < n[i]`? Also, this problem is much easier to solve with a `std::map`.

Comment: @cigien yeah, okay. That's not really serving the purpose. What do i do? Also, I haven't learnt map yet.

Comment: Note that here, after correction of the mentioned error, you will display the same information several times. Using a `std::map` will simplify everything here. Sorting is also an option.

Comment: @VasudhaJhingan One simple possibility would be to first scan the array for the lowest and highest values and then use those for the main loop.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple way to count frequencies of values:

```
std::map<int, int> freq;

for (int const i : n)
  freq[i]++;    // map has the nice property that it 
                // defaults the value of a key to 0

for (auto const &[i, count] : freq)  // this loop needs c++17
  std::cout << "Frequency of " << i << " is " << count << std::endl;
```

Comment: @VasudhaJhingan No problem :) Consider accepting the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: Good for real code (though add some `const`, dammit! :P) - but doesn't directly answer the question about the problem with _this_ code, and possibly advanced for an introductory C++ course (depending how it's structured). Doesn't teach algorithms, just teaches good C++ library usage.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings True, but OPs code I think is quite broken, there doesn't seem to be a clear algorithm being implemented. But where should I add `const`? Do you mean the first loop? It's just an `int`.

Comment: It's an `int` you're not changing ;)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Oh right, it's not a question of it being a copy. I read what I wanted from your comment :p Edited, thanks.

Comment: I had a feeling that might have been the case :P

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out that there are far better ways to do this.
Such as hashing

You can read About these here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-frequencies-of-array-elements/

Now I am gonna point out exactly where you went wrong.

in the first for loop replace  **`i < n[i]`**  with **`i<n.size()`**

Wrong:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < n[i]; i++)
```

Correct :

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < n.size(); i++)
```

Your code fails as when for `i=3` the value of `n[i]=3` which violated your for loop condition

Here this code will run for all repetitions of a number so it will print the same results multiple times and also will do all the calculation so maintain a
A visited array that stores the no which you have already calculated.

Here is your code but Corrected

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    array<unsigned int, 20> n = {1, 2, 5, 4, 3, 5, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2};
    vector<bool> visited(n.size(), false);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n.size(); i++)
    {
        int count = 0;
        // Skip this element if already processed
        if (visited[i] == true) continue;

        for (size_t j = 0; j < n.size(); j++){ 
            if (n[i] == n[j]){ 
                count++;
                // marking indexes already visited
                visited[j] = true;
            }
        }
        cout << "Frequency of " << n[i] << " is " << count << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But the best option is to learn Maps they are extremely helpful and are very easy to implement.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/map-associative-containers-the-c-standard-template-library-stl/

Comment: `n.size()`, not `n.size()-1`.

Comment: Ohhh I usually add the equal in loops my mistake I will correct it thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

Because this:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < n[i]; i++)
//                    ^^^^
```

…is wrong.

**You should be going up to `n.size()`.**

Currently, you're only going up to what happens to be `4` (`n[4]` is `3`, and `4 < 3` does not hold).

This was done right for the loop over `j`.

Answer (score -1):

As you use std::array so i assume you are fimiliar with `STL` so why not use its power to solve the problem.

Find The unique elemets first from your array.

```
std::unordered_set<int> s(n.begin(), n.end());
```

Than simply use `count` to give count of every element in your array.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
int main()
{
    std::array<unsigned int, 20> n = { 1, 2, 5, 4, 3, 5, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2 };
    std::unordered_set<int> s(n.begin(), n.end());

    for (const auto& itr : s) {
        std::cout << "Count of "<< itr << " Is equal to = " <<std::count(n.begin(), n.end(), itr) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: To person who negitive vote it! Mate at least explain why ?

Comment: Downvoted, because this solution while looking nicer and being less error prone is essentially the same flawed inefficient approach from the OP that uses unfitting (in a sense) STL constructs. If we go with unordered_set, why not just go with multiset to begin with? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multiset/count

Anyway, I'll retract my downvote if the caveat about the potential inefficiencies is added to the answer.

Comment: The only inefficent thing i see is the use of reference variable used inside for loop . If there is anyother thing please refer the study material that would be very kind of you.

Comment: For starters, your solution goes through all of the array to construct the unordered set, then for each element in the set you go through all of the array again. For the sequence of 1..N it'll run in ~N^2 steps.